# Why has the CSS margin no effect?

Tags: css, margin, margins

Aiming for: a vertical gap between paragraph and 'link-button'.

I seems I can change my margin for my link button to any number, but it seems to have no effect whatsoever. (I can surprisingly work around this by adding a margin-bottom in my 'paragraph' styling, yet it still bothers me that I don't know why I don't understand why code below is not working.)

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <style>
    .link {
        padding: 15px 30px;
        border: solid 2px black;
        margin-top: 600px; <!-- Why does this have no effect?-->
     }
     </style>
</head>


<body>
     <p>
​This is a paragraph text.
    </p>
    <a class="link" href="google.com">Google</a>
</body>
```

Comment: an `<a>` element is an *inline* element, this isn't affected by margin top, that's why changing the `display` to `inline-block` works.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

CSS:

```
.link {
    padding: 15px 30px;
    border: solid 2px black;
    margin-top: 600px; 
    display:inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: The fact that <a> is inline unless stated otherwise was the missing link! Thanks guys/girls for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Please add `display:inline-block` in `.link` css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <style>
    .link {
        padding: 15px 30px;
        border: solid 2px black;
        margin-top: 600px;
        display:inline-block;
     }
     </style>
</head>


<body>
     <p>
​This is a paragraph text.
    </p>
    <a class="link" href="google.com">Google</a>
</body>
```